# How to tailor {} in find -exec comand so that it shows folder name instead of full path?

Tags: linux, find, debian, exec, wine

Running Debian Buster 10.3 and bash "GNU bash, versión 5.0.3(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)"

data.exe *is a Windows program that creates an xml data file with checksums for every file in a directory:*

```
data.exe -t folderA /home/user/data/FolderA
```

-t *is a tag descriptor. I would like it to show the Folder name in each resulting  xml file instead of the full path. Filename is the Folder name. So filename is FolderA.dat*

data.exe *is run in Linux via wine*

Command or bash script should be able to perform described action recurrently

```
/home/user/data/
/home/user/data/FolderA
/home/user/data/FolderB
...
/home/user/data/FolderZ
```

In Debian:

```
find /home/user/data/ -type d -print -exec wine data.exe -t {} -o {}.dat {} \;
```

creates xml file correctly as FolderA.dat in path /home/user/data/

However, -t tag descriptor shows full path:

```
<tag>/home/user/data/FolderA</tag>
```

instead of desired folder name:

```
<tag>FolderA</tag>
```

So, is there a way to modify the output of {} the way I need? I have read and tried more combinations than I could possibly remember. Even assigned $pwd to a variable and customised that variable, but cannot pass that variable to the -exec as if it were the expected {}. If asked for, I could paste my history file so that anyone can see the zillion tests I have run as a Linux enthusiast. If the way to go is a bash script instead of one-liner command, welcome be it. After three days, I have to stop and ask for help.

Thank you in advance,

Edit:2020-02-26_16:30GMT

Just one issue: space `' '` and parentheses `'()'` are not interpreted.
Backslash `\` is usually used to escape those special characters.
Eg. from command line

```
user@debian:~$ wine data.exe -o Folder\ Beta.dat /home/user/data/Folder\ Beta
```

outputs `Folder Beta.dat` and `-t` tag correctly

It seems that `find` outputs the path as-is so the shell cannot interpret the path correctly. Using `sed` might help:

`eg. /home/user/data/Folder (Zeta)`

`find /home/user/data/ -type d | sed -e 's/ /\\ /g' | sed -e 's/(/\\(/g' | sed -e 's/)/\\)/g'`

outputs

`/home/user/data/Folder\ \(Zeta\)`

but how to get that output as input in the `-exec sh -c` part of the `find` command?

Following the example:

```
/home/user/data/
/home/user/data/FolderAlpha
/home/user/data/Folder Beta
/home/user/data/Folder-Gamma
/home/user/data/Folder(Delta)
/home/user/data/Folder[Epsilon]

/home/user/data/FolderAlpha
outputs FolderAlpha.dat and -t tag correctly

/home/user/data/Folder Beta
Aborted processing due to errors!

/home/user/data/Folder-Gamma
outputs Folder-GammaAlpha.dat and -t tag correctly

/home/user/data/Folder(Delta
Aborted processing due to errors!
/home/user/data/Folder(Delta: 1: /home/user/data/Folder(Delta: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
/home/user/data/FolderDelta)
Aborted processing due to errors!
/home/user/data/FolderDelta): 1: /home/user/data/FolderDelta): Syntax error: ")" unexpected

/home/user/data/Folder[Epsilon
outputs Folder[Epsilon.dat and -t tag correctly
/home/user/data/FolderEpsilon]
outputs FolderEpsilon].dat and -t tag correctly
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) of the form `${parameter##word}` to delete the path head:

```
find /home/user/data/ -type d -print -exec sh -c 'wine data.exe -t ${0##*/} -o {}.dat {}' {} \;
```

> … one issue: space `' '` and parentheses `'()'` …

For this we just have to quote the names at the three places where they appear within the shell command:

```
find /home/user/data/ -type d -print -exec sh -c 'wine data.exe -t "${0##*/}" -o "{}".dat "{}"' {} \;
```

Comment: Thank you indeed. I wouldn't have achieved that. Appreciate the explanation, informative link and your example. Just one issue: space `' '` and parentheses `'()'` are not interpreted. Backslash `\` is usually used to escape those special characters. Eg. from command line
`user@debian:~$ wine data.exe -o Folder\ Beta.dat /home/user/data/Folder\ Beta`
outputs `Folder Beta.dat` and `-t` tag correctly. Is there a way to do it in the find -exec command? Extended explanation in main topic question due to Comment space-limited constraints. Thank you once more,

Comment: Excellent! Thumbs up.